# SQL count occurrences multiple columns

Tags: sql

From the following table, I would like to count 1) the number of distinct names and 2) the number of occurrences of each name.

```
+------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| date | job  |person1|person2|person3|person4|person5|
+------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| mon  | clean|  Matt | Bruce | Alan  |Emilce | Linda |
+------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| tu   | write| Bruce |  Matt |  Matt | Alan  | Linda |
+------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| wen  | mend | Bruce |Emilce |  Matt |  Matt | Linda |
+------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| fri  | sew  |  Matt | Linda |Emilce | Alan  | Alan  |
+------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

The output should be:
Names number: 5

Number of occurrences of each name:

```
+------+------+
| Alan |  4   |
+------+------+
| Bruce|  3   |
+------+------+
|Emilce|  3   |
+------+------+
| Linda|  4   |
+------+------+
| Matt |  5   |
+------+------+
```

I've been trying with

```
SELECT user, count(*) AS count
FROM (
SELECT person1 AS user FROM mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT person1 FROM mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT person3 FROM mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT person4 FROM mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT person5 FROM mytable
) AS all_users
GROUP BY user
ORDER BY user
```

But I don´t know how to know the number of names present in the table, and I would like to get the number of occurrences of each name in an array.

Comment: Which database are you using? Oracle?

Comment: Aside from for selecting person 1 twice, this should work. How is it not working for you?

Comment: If $persons=mysql_query('SELECT ...'); $person1=mysql_result($persons,1); But don't know how many there are, in order to loop through all of them

Comment: It seems that the answer provided by Gordon is pretty close to what you want. I do not understand why you did not respond to his answer but instead added your own answer mixed with php.

Comment: threeForOneSixOneThree: youre right. I'm not very fast in checking the proposed code. +1 for Gordon. And since what I originally wrote was not that bad, I wanted to retreat the question but dont know how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT count(distinct user) as NumNames
FROM (
SELECT person1 AS user FROM mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT person1 FROM mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT person3 FROM mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT person4 FROM mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT person5 FROM mytable
) all_users
```

Answer (score -1):

The above code actually is working.
mysql_result($Persons,0,1) is indeed the total number of names present in the table.
So you can loop to get all the names/occurences pairs.
I didn´t notice.
My apologies.

```
$Persons=mysql_query('SELECT user, count(*) AS count
FROM (
SELECT person1 AS user FROM mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT person1 FROM mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT person3 FROM mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT person4 FROM mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT person5 FROM mytable
) AS all_users
GROUP BY user
ORDER BY user');

$TotalPersons=mysql_result($Persons,0,1);

for ($i=0;$i<=$TotalPersons;$i++) {
   $Name[$i]=mysql_result($Persons,$i+1);
   $Occurences[$i]=mysql_result($Persons,$i+1,1);

   echo "<br> Number".$i.": ".$Name[$i].": ".$Occurences[$i]."<br>";
}
```